# Add new column with name of max column in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

So I've got this example `df`:

```
df <- dput(structure(list(arts = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("art1", "art2"), class = "character"), scr1 = c(52L, 58L, 40L, 62L), scr2 = c(25L, 23L, 55L, 26L), scr3 = c(36L, 60L, 19L, 22L)), .Names = c("art_id", "scr1", "scr2", "scr3"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame"))

> df
  art_id scr1 scr2 scr3
1      1   52   25   36
2      1   58   23   60
3      3   40   55   19
4      4   62   26   22
```

That I'm using `dplyr` to summarize by `art_id`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(art_id) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(sum))

  art_id  scr1  scr2  scr3
   <int> <int> <int> <int>
1      1   110    48    96
2      3    40    55    19
3      4    62    26    22
```

**My question**:  How can I add another column called `top_r` that contains the column name from the maximum among `src1:src3`. The resultant df would look like:

```
  art_id  scr1  scr2  scr3  top_r
   <int> <int> <int> <int>  <char>
1      1   110    48    96   scr1  
2      3    40    55    19   scr2  
3      4    62    26    22   scr1
```

I am comfortable using `dplyr` so if there's an answer that uses that library that's wonderful!

Comment: @Henrik I don't think this is a duplicate. There are columns that should not be considered (row identifiers) which makes the situation here slightly different and the most accepted answer from the other thread cannot be used in this case. It would even be wrong, because it would also evaluate `art_id` in this example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work:

```
df %>%
  group_by(art_id) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum)) %>%
  mutate(top_r=apply(.[,2:4], 1, function(x) names(x)[which.max(x)]))

# A tibble: 3 × 5
  art_id  scr1  scr2  scr3 top_r
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>
1      1   110    48    96  scr1
2      3    40    55    19  scr2
3      4    62    26    22  scr1
```

Comment: What if you wanted to add the max value instead of the column name?

Comment: @zsad512 The last two lines would be   `summarise_all(funs(sum)) %>%
  mutate(max=apply(.[,2:4], 1, max))`

Answer (score 5):

Its just this simple in base R using `max.col`:

```
df$top_r <- names(df)[-1][max.col(df[-1])]
```

Comment: whoa - that _is_ simple.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(art_id) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(sum))

df3 <- df2 %>%
  gather(top_r, Value, -art_id) %>%
  arrange(art_id, desc(Value)) %>%
  group_by(art_id) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  select(-Value)

df_final <- df2 %>%
  left_join(df3, by = "art_id")

df_final
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  art_id  scr1  scr2  scr3 top_r
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>
1      1   110    48    96  scr1
2      3    40    55    19  scr2
3      4    62    26    22  scr1
```